# Play WAV files one after the other in Java

Tags: java, audio, concatenation, wav, sequential

I'm trying to play a few [WAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) files after each other. I tried this method:

```
for (String file : audioFiles) {
    new AePlayWave(file).start();
}
```

But that plays them all at the same time. So I need a function that looks like this:

```
public void play(Vector<String> audioFiles);
```

The vector contains the files, for example: `"test1.wav"`,`"test2.wav"`

I have been looking for over four hours, but I can't seem to find a working solution :(

I also tried concatenating the WAV files to one AudioInputStream. It doesn't give any compiler errors, but the sound is totally messed up. Code:

```
public static AudioInputStream concat(Vector<String> files) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException {
    AudioInputStream total = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(files.get(0)));

    for (int i = 1; i < files.size(); i++) {
        AudioInputStream clip = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(files.get(i)));
        total = new AudioInputStream(new SequenceInputStream(total, clip),
                                     total.getFormat(),
                                     total.getFrameLength() + clip.getFrameLength());
    }
    return total;
}
```

**Edit**

Even if I try to put the two first files together, it fails:

```
public static AudioInputStream concat(Vector<String> files) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException {
    AudioInputStream clip1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(files.get(0)));
    AudioInputStream clip2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(files.get(1)));

    AudioInputStream total = new AudioInputStream(
        new SequenceInputStream(clip1, clip2),
        clip1.getFormat(),
        clip1.getFrameLength() + clip2.getFrameLength());

    return total;
}
```

Comment: Your method to try to concatenate the files definitely won't work as coded because you're overwriting `total` at every iteration.

Comment: yes but i overwrite it with a combination of the total and the next clip

or is there still something wrong with it? (it does sound like i'm overwriting it :) )

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is a bit low-level, but it works:

```
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    for (File file : files) {
        try {
            AudioInputStream is = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
            AudioFormat format = is.getFormat();
            SourceDataLine line = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(format);
            line.open(format);
            line.start();
            while (is.available() > 0) {
                int len = is.read(buffer);
                line.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            line.drain(); //**[DEIT]** wait for the buffer to empty before closing the line
            line.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Basically you open an AudioInputStream, read data and write it to a SourceDataLine. `write` method is blocking, so it will play files consequently.

You can try to use `Clip` for the same purpose.

Comment: this works but the audio gets cut of every time at the end of every file

if you want to play the files: 
hello.wav
and_welcome.wav
to_stackoverflow.wav

you hear:
hel and welco to stackove



any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: @Berty: add line.drain() before line.close()

Comment: perfect  that did the trick
thx so much

it sound perfect now :D

Answer (score 1):

The final answer (with drain):

```
public static void play(ArrayList<String> files){
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    for (String filePath : files) {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        try {
            AudioInputStream is = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
            AudioFormat format = is.getFormat();
            SourceDataLine line = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(format);
            line.open(format);
            line.start();
            while (is.available() > 0) {
                int len = is.read(buffer);
                line.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            line.drain();
            line.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```